# Compiler recognizing wrong function with same name

Tags: c++, qt, namespaces

Im implementing a new slot which just has to call the method `reset()`. My new class is subclassing `QAbstractListModel` in which `QAbstractListModel::reset()` exists.

```
//stationlist.h
class StationListModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
...
public slots:
    void dataChanged();

//stationlist.cpp    
...
void StationListModel::dataChanged()
{
reset();
}
```

However, in the implementation the method `reset()` is recognized as `QTextStream::reset()` and doesn't compile because of this. What could be the cause for such behaviour?

Comment: actually there isn't a [QAbstractListModel::reset()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qabstractlistmodel-members.html)

Comment: Where this `QTextStream` comes from? It is not clear from the sample code.

Comment: Try calling it with its scope: QAbstractListModel::reset, without seeing the rest of the code, it sounds like the compiler is a little confused - I assume you've done the obvious clean build!

Comment: follow documentation [notes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#reset) and use `beginResetModel()` and `endResetModel()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment, the conclusion is that the method `QAbstractListModel::reset()` doesn't exist.

It is here only still available fer backwards compatibility http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qabstractitemmodel-compat.html#reset.

I believe that `QTextStream::reset()` is just something that the QtCreator offered as a global autocomplete.

The solution is to use non deprecated method.